# Unable to rotate object in normal orientation

Tags: transform-orientation

I have such a simple problem, I am blocking out my scene and I am just using simple boxes to model a chair. I want the rest of the chair to rotated but I am unable to rotate it along it's normal orientation.

[image]

Note: I did rotate the bottom part of the chair and I have duplicated the rest from it. I have also applied Location, Rotation & scaling to the object.

Thank you,
W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood the question you want to rotate the rest back to rotate.

Select the back rest.

In edit mode select the edge and Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
Cursor to selected.

Change the Pivot point to 3D Cursor

In object mode rotate now.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly how it should work, however I still have a little trouble and I can show you. Could you tell me how you record your screen and make a gif and I can share with you.

Comment: @iowaqas You can find several methods [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/963/935)